# How to add a new column to data-frame that depends on values from another column?

Tags: r

Let's say I have to following data frame (called myData):

```
X
1
2
3
4
```

Now I want to add another column Y(x) like the following

```
X   Y
1   max(0, min(a*x+rnorm(1, 183, 10), 4) 
2   max(0, min(a*x+rnorm(1, 183, 10), 4) 
3   max(0, min(a*x+rnorm(1, 183, 10), 4)
4   max(0, min(a*x+rnorm(1, 183, 10), 4)
```

Where the small x is the value of x at that specific row and "a" is just a constant. Where 4 is nrow(myData).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```r
# Base R 
dat <- data.frame("X" = 1:4)           
dat$Y = pmax(0, pmin(1*dat$X+rnorm(n=4, 183, 10), n=nrow(dat)))
```

**EDIT:** As per the comments below, I adjusted it to use the proper functions and allowed it to be dynamic to number of rows in DF.

Comment: This is wrong and I was going to post a similar, but correct, result. You should replace `min` and `max` with `pmin` and `pmax`. You should also replace `n=4` with `n=nrow(dat)`, to make it work with any size datasets.

Comment: That's not wrong, it's just different from what OP asked to use.

Comment: I guess that for each row a random number is drawn and compared to 0 and 4. Your way, by design, the `Y` column will contain the same value for every row.

Comment: Made changes, `tibble()` wasn't liking me referencing `nrow(X)`

Comment: You put `nrow(dat)` in as an argument `pmax`, but in the question `4` is an argument to `min`, not `max`. This means that now `max` has an extra argument and `pmin` isn't doing anything at all since there's only one argument.

Comment: To be fair, that has little to do with OP's question as they were just trying to understand how to create a column dependent on another column.

Comment: hardly a complex calculation where they used an undefined variable in its definition. Don't take SO too seriously dude.